# How do I pause a sound track?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

```
function playMusic(){
    var music = new Audio('musicfile.mp3');

    music.play();
}

<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="playMusic()" />
```

The sound plays when I click on it, but if I click on it again, it plays it twice, I'm just looking for a way to be able to play and pause. Thanks.

Comment: `music.pause();` and assigns values ​​using toggle click, or through the counter

Answer (score 0):

Here is a counter-clicked implementation.

```js
let clickPosition = 0;
  var music = new Audio('http://freshly-ground.com//data/audio/mpc/20151115%20-%20Mashmakhan%20Beat%20-%20The%20Orchestra%20%28Dynamic%20Compressor%201.2.6%29.mp3');
  
  function playMusic() {
    music.play();
  }

  function pauseMusic() {
    music.pause();
  }

  function liveMusic() {
    if (clickPosition == 0) { 
      playMusic();
      console.log('music play');
      clickPosition = 1;
    } else {
      pauseMusic();
      console.log('music pause');
      clickPosition = 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="sound" onclick="liveMusic()"/>
```

Comment: Check my solution, please.

Comment: if my answer helped you, please check the green checkmark :)